# using case default on switch statement returns "The preview feature Pattern Matching in Switch is only available with source level 20 and above"

Tags: java, switch-statement

```
package com.learningjava.conditionals;

public class SwitchExcercises {

    public static boolean isWeekDay(int dayNumber) {
        switch (dayNumber) {
        case 0:
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
            return true;
        case 5:
        case 6:
            return false;
        case default:
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Eclipse as my ide. Shows error next to case default, says

```
The preview feature Pattern Matching in Switch is only available with source level 20 and above.
```

Using java-se 17. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The error message is here misleading: it's only `default:`, not `case default:`.

Comment: ??? Just replace `case default` with `default` (without `case`) and everything is fine. The error message `The preview feature Pattern Matching in Switch is only available with source level 20 and above` you got from the IDE is misleading, so just ignore it.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The syntax of the [switch statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) is incorrect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a syntax error where the code you meant to write is actually trying to do something entirely different than you intended. Your syntax error accidentally overlapped with a brand new Java Feature called [Pattern Matching for switch Expressions and Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/language/pattern-matching-switch-expressions-and-statements.html).

To fix the error, just switch `case default` to say just `default`.

```
case default:
    return false;
```

to

```
default:
    return false;
```

And to better explain the error message, Eclipse the IDE is aware of the new Java feature, and thus, is trying to let you know that what you are doing looks like the new feature, and that if you are trying to do the new feature, you should upgrade your code level to 21 or above.

But of course, Eclipse got it wrong - you just want a default clause. So write it like I showed you above, and the error should go away.

Answer (score 6):

Also, note that what you are doing is morally an expression, and you can express it as such:

```
    return switch (dayNumber) {
        case 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 -> true;
        case 5, 6 -> false;
        default -> false;
    }
```

Or even

```
return switch (dayNumber) {
    case 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 -> true;
    default -> false;
}
```

since the intention here is "true if in 0..4, false otherwise".

Comment: Yep, [JEP 361](https://openjdk.org/jeps/361) (nice that a Java language developer answers a beginner's question).

Comment: I've never heard "morally" used in this context (usually something like "conceptually" or "semantically"), but I do grok it.

Comment: I think, in the shown form with `default -> false`, the `switch` is not better than `return dayNumber >=0 && dayNumber <= 4;` A more interesting example would be `return switch (dayNumber) { case 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 -> true; case 5, 6 -> false; default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException("not a week day number: " + dayNumber); };`